# Why doesn't Outlook warn me anymore when I add an already occupied meetingroom to the appointment?

Tags: exchange, outlook-2007, warning

We use outlook 2007 and Exchange 2003. When i add the meetingroom to the appointment it doesn't warn me anymore that the meetingroom is already occupied. The same happens to all my colleagues, so I think it is something in Exchange. Any idea where I can solve this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me as if the Meeting Room hasn't been correctly set up as a Resource so that it can't be double booked. You need to set up the Meeting Room with a real mailbox (not a public folder calendar) and then configure that account to "Automatically decline conflicting meeting requests".